# PHP unset array key for empty value not working

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason I can not determine why empty array keys aren't being `unset`. Here is what I have...

**PHP**

```
<?php
$attachments = explode('|',$_POST['post_attachments']);
foreach($attachments as $k=>$v)
{
echo 'k = \''.$v."'\n";
 if ($v=='')
 {
  unset($k);
 }
}
print_r($attachments);die();
?>
```

**Output**

> k = ''
>
> k = 'secret_afound.gif'
>
> k = 'secret_aunlocked.gif'
>
> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => 
> [1] => secret_afound.gif
> [2] => secret_aunlocked.gif
> ```
>
> )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do:

```
foreach ($attachments as $k=>$v) {
    //...magic
    unset($attachments[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm in such a rush, worked! Thanks! Will accept when the limit expires.

Answer (score 0):

You are only unsetting `$k`, not the element in attachments.  Try `unset($attachments[$k]);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `unset($attachments[$k])`;.

In this scenario I like to think of `$k` as a temporary variable. Even though you `unset` it you didn't alter `$attachments` in anyway.